# Move Sharepoint 2010 to point to a different database?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010

Has anyone here moved the database underlying a SP 2010 install from one database instance to another (same data, just hosted in another instance)?

For example. we just want to move the database to a diffrerent machine.

In addition, has anyone moved SP 2010 from using SQL Express to a higher version of SQL Server?  I would like to run some proof of concept tests with SQL Express, and if all goes well, then move to SQL Standard or Enterprise.

Cheers,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll run into any problems, just make sure you aren't going backwards in versions between databases. Backing up a database in SQL Server 2008 and restoring in 2005 isn't easy.

I've never done this with SharePoint, but I believe it lets you specify the location of the configuration database. Then you just need to match the user permissions.

Comment: I do know how to move SQL Server databases back and forth.  The question really is about Sharepoint and how to move its back-end databases.  I'm very new to the product and trying to get my head around the database back end.

Answer (score 0):

The TechNet article ["Move All Databases (SharePoint 2010)"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx) is your main guide.

Note that this article contains the following warning:

> The new database server must be running **the same version** of Windows
>   Server and **Microsoft SQL Server** as the existing database server.

This in NOT true!

Both from my own experience in migrating SharePoint databases and talks I've had with Microsoft Primary Field Engineering, I can say this method also works when SQL Server versions differ. But only if you upgrade to higher SQL Server versions (i.e. SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 R2). I was told this scenario is also fully supported by Microsoft.

Also, don't forget to update the database compatibility level for the migrated databases. This should future-proof your databases and enable advanced SQL Server optimization.